# How to position a THREE.PerspectiveCamera on an object of different sizes

Tags: javascript, graphics, three.js, camera

I am trying to position my THREE.PerspectiveCamera in a specific manner wrt. to my (main) displayed object.
In all cases, I want my camera to look at the object in the same way, e.g.

w=3, h=1, d=1
[image: w=3, h=1, d=1]

w=3, h=1, d=100
[image: w=e, h=1, d=100]

and so on.

I tried computing the cameras position wrt. to my reference point (in my case the corner on the left front), like so:

```
camera.position.x = 1.5 * (refX + w);
camera.position.y = 1.5 * (refY + h);
camera.position.z = 1.5 * (refZ - d);
```

What I observe:

- If I change w/h/d in the same fashion, it works
- In all other cases, the camera either hangs in the cube or is wayy to far away

Really appreciate any help, thanks in advance!